# What exactly is the difference between fuse2 and fuse3?

Tags: linux, fuse

FUSE = Filesystem in user space recommends that distros package both a fuse2 and a fuse3 (see [here](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/releases)) and indeed they do.

What exactly is the reason for this? Is it just that the init code in fuse3 is different?

Answer (score 11):

The [release notes for libfuse 3.0.0](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/releases/tag/fuse-3.0.0) appear comprehensive. Read below the heading 'Changes (since FUSE 2.9)'. Functions have been renamed for clarity, functions dropped and parameters tidied up. Here are a few examples from the release notes to give a flavour:

- The `fuse_lowlevel_new` function has been renamed to
  `fuse_session_new` and no longer interprets the --version or --help
  options
- `fuse_loop()`, `fuse_loop_mt()`, `fuse_session_loop()` and `fuse_session_loop_mt()` now return more detailed error codes instead of just -1. See the documentation of fuse_session_loop() for details
- There are new `fuse_session_unmount` and `fuse_session_mount`
  functions that should be used in the low-level API. The `fuse_mount`
  and `fuse_unmount` functions should be used with the high-level API
  only
- The `fuse_invalidate` function has been removed

Installing libfuse2 alongside libfuse3 allows applications using libfuse2 to keep working without needing to be updated straight away.

Comment: `apt install libfuse2` was what I needed to be able to run the older apps without uninstalling fuse3.